# Drive API v3.0 support for GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to get the highlighted text of a document comment using GAS?

I'd like to use Drive API v3.0 which has `quotedFileContent.value` but GAS is only supporting Drive API v2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I published an Apps Script library for Drive V3. You can check it out at:

https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Drive-v3-Library